# ¿Cómo cambiar la carpeta ext del framework a una URL externa?

Tags: javascript, extjs

La carpeta "ext" de una aplicación de Ext js es muy pesada a la hora de subirla al repositorio, así que hemos pensado en subirla a nuestro servidor local y así no tener que lidiar con la carpeta a la hora de crear un nuevo proyecto.

El problema es que el cmd de sencha no es capaz de encontrarla cuando la tenemos fuera del proyecto.

Esto es mi workspace.json:

```
{
    "frameworks": {
        "ext": {
            // esto es lo más cerca a lo que he llegado
            "path":"C:/ext",
            "version":"6.2.0.981"
        }
    },

    "build": {
        "dir": "${workspace.dir}/build"
    },

    "packages": {
        "dir": "${workspace.dir}/packages/local,${workspace.dir}/packages",

        "extract": "${workspace.dir}/packages/remote"
    }
}
```

Existe algo como : `"path":"localhost/ext"`?

Comment: Gracias por avisar  lois6b.

Comment: Sin problema, ya he votado para reabrirla

Answer (score 0):

Al final hemos adaptado la estructura de Sencha para varias aplicaciones en un mismo workspace y la hemos subido al repositorio.
Un par de modificaciones el workspace.json y va perfecto.

Comment: Es perfectamente valido de solucionar su propio problema en una respuesta. Existe la posibilidad de concretar un poco los "par de modificaciónes"?